# LISP Combining two list of integers and sorting them in ascending order?

Tags: lisp, scheme, racket

I have no problem combining the lists but sorting them in ascending order is where i am struggling.

```
 (define (combineASC l1 l2)
   (cond 
     ((null? l1) l2)
     (#t (cons (car l1) (combineASC (cdr l1) l2)))
     (sort l2 #'<))) ; I found this part in an online source
```

This is the output i get:

```
(combineASC '(2 4 6) '(1 4 5))

(2 4 6 1 4 5)
```

Does anyone have any suggestions for me?

Comment: ya they are also sorted in ascending order

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So you're combining two input lists, each already sorted in ascending order. You want to "weave" them into one, also in ascending order.

For that, you just take both head elements (each from each input list) and compare; then you take the smallest out from its list, and combine further what you're left with - using same function.

There will be no sorting involved. The resulting list will be already sorted, by virtues of the process that defines it.

This operation is commonly called "merge". It preserves duplicates. Its duplicates-removing counterpart, merging two ordered lists into one as well, is known a "union". That is because these ordered (non-descending, or strictly ascending) lists can be seen as representation of sets.

---

Another subtlety to take note of is, what to do when the two head elements are equal. We've already decided to preserve the duplicates, yes, but *which* of the two to take out first?

Normally, it's the left one. Then when such defined `merge` operation is used as part of *merge sort*, the sort will be *stable* (of course the partitioning has to be defined properly for that too). Stable means, the original order of elements is preserved.

For example, if the sort is stable, when sorting by the first element of pairs, `(3,1) (1,2) (3,3)` is guaranteed to be sorted as `(1,2) (3,1) (3,3)` and not as `(1,2) (3,3) (3,1)`.

So, following the skeleton of your code, we get

```
;; combine two non-decreasing lists into one non-decreasing list,
;; preserving the duplicates
(define (combineNONDECR l1 l2)
   (cond 
     ((null? l1) l2)
     ((null? l2) l1)
     ((<= (car l1) (car l2))
      (cons (car l1) (combineNONDECR (cdr l1) l2)))
     (t
      (cons (car l2) (combineNONDECR l1 (cdr l2))))))
```

But if you really need the result to be in *ascending* order, as opposed to *non-decreasing*, then you'd have to tweak this a little bit - make the `=` case separate, and handle it separately, to stop the duplicates from creeping in (there are no duplicates in each of the ascending-order lists, but the lists might contain some duplicates between the two of them).

Answer (score 1):

Because tail recursive :)

```
(define (merge-sorted . lists)
  (define (%merge-sorted head tails)
    (cond
     ((null? tails) head)
     ((null? (car tails))
      (%merge-sorted head (cdr tails)))
     (else (let ((sorted
                  (sort tails
                        (lambda (a b)
                          (<= (car a) (car b))))))
             (%merge-sorted (cons (caar sorted) head)
                            (cons (cdar sorted) (cdr sorted)))))))
  (reverse (%merge-sorted '() lists)))

(merge-sorted '(1 2 3) '(4 5 6 7 8 9) '(2 4 6) '(1 3 5 7))
```

- it scales better :P

---

I think this is what Will was talking about:

```
(define (merge-sorted . lists)
  (define (%swap-if-greater lists)
    (define (%do-swap head next built tails)
      (cond
       ((null? tails)
        (append (reverse built)
                (cond
                 ((null? next) (list head))
                 ((> (car head) (car next))
                    (list next head))
                 (else (list head next)))))
       ((> (car head) (car next))
        (%do-swap head (car tails)
                  (cons next built) (cdr tails)))
       (else (append (reverse built)
                     (list head) (list next) tails))))
    (%do-swap (car lists)
              (if (null? (cdr lists)) '() (cadr lists))
              '() (if (null? (cdr lists)) '() (cddr lists))))
  (define (%merge-sorted head tails)
    (cond
     ((null? tails) head)
     ((null? (car tails))
      (%merge-sorted head (cdr tails)))
     (else (let ((sorted (%swap-if-greater tails)))
             (%merge-sorted (cons (caar sorted) head)
                            (cons (cdar sorted)
                                  (cdr sorted)))))))
  (reverse
   (%merge-sorted
    '() (sort lists (lambda (a b) (<= (car a) (car b)))))))
```

Especially given Schemes... interesting position on booleans, I wouldn't be very enthusiastic about this one.

Comment: (append (list x) y) == ... :)

Comment: sort on each "yield" is a bit overkill too (even if on short list). better done just once at the start,  and then - change that form with `cons` to `(insert-by-head (cdar sorted) (cdr sorted))`... :)

Comment: I thought if we sort just once, at the start; and then go into the loop; then we start with the lists sorted, take out the first element from the first list, and then if we insert that tail of the first list into the rest of lists, we get again the sorted list of lists.

Comment: ... I thought more along the lines of `(else (%merge-sorted (cons (caar tails) head) (%insert (cons (cdar tails) (cdr tails)))))` with `(define (%insert a b) (if (<= (car a)(caar b))(cons a b) (cons (car b) (%insert a (cdr b)))))` (plus corner cases).

Comment: I guess so, yes. I'd just enforce "tails is sorted" constraint in a little bit different order: `tails` is already sorted on 1st entry to `%merge-sorted` so I'd re-establish their order on exit, with `(%insert...)`. And then `%insert` receives its two arguments directly, which lets it to be a little bit shorter, like so `(define (%insert a b) (if (null? a) b (let loop ((r ()) (b b)) (cond ((null? b) (reverse (cons a r))) ((<= (car a) (caar b)) (append (reverse r) (cons a b))) (else (loop (cons (car b) r) (cdr b)))))))`. _Named let_ is the Scheme way to encode loops. Nice idea w/ dotted arg! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
(defun merge (l1 l2)
 (if (not (and (eql nil l1) (eql l2 nil))
  (if (> (car l1) (car l2))
     (cons (car l1) (merge (cdr l1) l2))
    (cons (car l2) (merge (cdr l2) l1)))
  ;;;append the not-nil string to the rest.
  )
```

that should work (you still need to complete the code, but the idea is clear)

**note** this code is in common-lisp.

look up [merge sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort) for more info about the technique

Comment: [1]> (append 1 (list 2 3))

*** - APPEND: 1 is not a list
The following restarts are available:
ABORT          :R1      ABORT

Comment: @WillNess oops. fixed, but if you have a better suggestion, I well love to see. (I don't really know lisp)

Comment: What Will is pointing out is this: if you know you're adding an element to the head of a list, use *cons*, not *append*.  That is, the pattern *(append (list X) Y)* is much more naturally expressed as *(cons X Y)*.